# Two identical Linq queries, one stopped working - on hold

Tags: visual-studio, linq, azure

I am maintaining an application on Azure on which two projects of the same solution share the same database and the same libraries, but each has a copy of the exact same version of a Linq query.

After working for a while, one of them stopped and now returns no lines (0) all the time. Here is it:

```
public static int GetUnreadMessageCount(User user, IUnitOfWork _uow)
{
    var query = _uow.ConversationMessageRepository.Query(
         m => m.Conversation.ConversationUsers.Any(u => u.TenantUserID == user.ID));
    return query.count();
}
```

However, it is obvious the problem doesn't come from here, since one of the two Linq queries is still running fine!

What can cause a Linq query to return 0 in a project and the correct number in another (but being in the same solution) ?

**Added information - Feb 3rd**

A precision about the code:

- the last update on the server what around December 15th
- the issue started on Jan 16th

**Update - Feb 4th**

I made a strange discovery: the query is actually working at certain hours during the day.  At the hour when the batch runs, however, the query returns zero lines.

**Update - Feb 6th**

I place this question on hold, because the origin of the problem seems to be on the Azure server.

**Update - Feb 14th**

I created a lot of traces on this application.  I now believe that the server acts as expected, but that the code have been working by accident.  All variables may not be properly instantiated (thanks @ Pete M).
A happy customer soon?

Comment: How did you test? Did you ensure proper functionality of the concrete objects you used to implement IUnitOfWork and/or ConversationMessageRepository? Can you call both static functions with the same User and IUnitOfWork instances and get different results?

Comment: If it is obvious that the issue doesn't come from this code then you should try to find the code where the error does come from. Otherwise how can we can answer this?

Comment: We have no idea what all these objects in your code look like (`user, _uow, ConversationMessageRepository`) and what their lifecycle is. Queries that "suddenly" start misbehaving (nearly) always have to do with context instances being used in multiple threads.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, Ashkan!

Comment: @Pete: I tested the behaviour in their natural context.  One of these is a batch which unfortunately can run only on the server.  I guess I can modify it to run locally and check the IUnitOfWork, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @Enigmativity: yes, the question I am asking isn't sufficient to give an answer.  Sorry about that!  I am wondering if someone already observed this kind of behaviour and could tell me where I should search in priority?

Comment: @Gert Arnold: It makes sense (I guess it relates to what Pete M said above?).  I am trying to figure precisely this hypothesis: some contextual information changed which cause the issue.  I have  tested the User ID, which is correct, I have yet to test the _UOW and the ConversationMessageRepository then...

Comment: @Manor - Stack Overflow isn't like other forums. Here we strive to create a library of quality questions and answers for the entire community. We're not primarily here to help the question poster. We're not here to give you hints. You really should try to add enough information for us to solve your issue - or if not then delete the question.